# Greatest Value Decision

Tags: algorithm, logic

I am writing function to give greatest value from list of values. My question is being what if all values are being the same? For examples,

```
30,29,34,45
```

Easy. Greatest value is 45. Now,

```
20,20,20,20
```

Is greatest value here is 20? Or is there no greatest value? I am confused about this.

This is important for me because I have to removing one element which is greatest value and these are money amounts so very important I not dong this wrong as then customer bill will be wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to the requirements of the code. This should be clarified by whomever the code is being written for.

Answer (score 1):

In all languages I know, the buildin `max` will returns `20`. So it is commons that the greatest would be `20`. A basic algorithm looks like this:

```
let result = first element of list
foreach number in list
    if number is greater than result
        result = number

return result
```

Now, you will have to check if you have to remove the one greatest value or all of them. We cannot decice this for you or your client. Tips, ask them.

Comment: Thanks you sir. Yes I code like this. Otherwise if remove all then customer has zero bill and they get all things for free - hahahaha

Comment: @Mojo here is the C# implementation of [`Max`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1747) with a special check to verify that the input contains any value.